ИИ ответы или невероятно продуктивный участник
Уже не первый раз мне попадается товарищь Matvj, невероятно продуктивный участник.
Его кто-то лайкает, иногда ему даже везёт и его ответы принимают, но неизменно одно, что ни ответ - это целое эссе.
На мой вкус, просто не возможно за пару часов вникать в разные вопросы от ассемблера до питона и строчить километровые ответы один за одним..
Что не ответ, прям образец форматирования. Вот только содержание зачастую очень странное. Складывается впечатление, что это бездумная копипаста из какой-то нейросети 1 2 3 и т.д...
Собственно вопрос, как на это реагировать? 

Да конечно это чатгпт. Я помню ему пару ответов дизлайкнул и сказал, что мол не нужна тут эта простыня от ИИ - так он их удалил зато

@Byb пройтись и минусануть ему все подозрительные ответы явно не выход (он может их и не удалить), за это самому прилетит ответка от внутренних алгоритмов сайта (если я верно понимаю). Так что тут нужна какая-то другая реакция..

Ставьте тревогу, выбирайте "требуется вмешательство модератора", пишите, что (вероятно) ChatGPT.

Если сейчас смотреть на его профиль и стату, то ничего странного с первого взгляда не попадается. Примерно один ответ в пару дней.  Работа для модеров

@Dmitry как видно часть ответов уже удалил, но даже те что остались всё равно странные.

Я понял свою ошибку. Те ответы, которые минусанули и посчитали плохими я удалил. Те, которые приняли или проголосовали или рейтинг 0 и больше я сделал общими.

@Matvj общими (wiki) ответы надо делать тогда, когда ответ создаётся совместными усилиями нескольких участников, а не одним человеком. Я отменил статус общих у ответов.

Ставьте тревогу, выбирайте "требуется вмешательство модератора", пишите, что (вероятно) ChatGPT.© insolor
